# Upgrade Python Script to QGIS3

Tags: python, qgis-3, export

We are now using QGIS 3.12.
Our basic python script from earlier QGIS version  to export to Mapinfo and mid/mif seems to no longer work. 
I understand QGIS 3+ has upgraded this functionality. and i have no idea where to start to fix this.

Can someone please advise how to run the below script, or advise how to upgrade it also?
Can someone please review?

```py
from qgis.gui import*
from qgis.core import *
import os

def run_script(iface):
    PATH = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")
    MifPath = PATH + '/Submit/MID_MIF/'
    ShapePath = PATH + '/Submit/ESRI_SHAPE/'        

    if not os.path.exists(MifPath):
        os.mkdir(MifPath)
    if not os.path.exists(ShapePath):
        os.mkdir(ShapePath)

    for vLayer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( vLayer, 
        MifPath + vLayer.name() + ".mif", "utf-8", 
        vLayer.crs(), 'Mapinfo File', datasourceOptions='FORMAT=MIF')

    for vLayer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat( vLayer, 
        ShapePath + vLayer.name() + ".shp", "utf-8", 
        vLayer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile" )

    from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox
    QMessageBox.information(None, "MapInfo Mif/Mid Exported to", "" + unicode(MifPath))
    QMessageBox.information(None, "ESRI Shapefile to", "" + unicode(ShapePath))
```

Answer (score 2):

A Python3 and QGIS 3 version would be :

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from qgis.gui import*
from qgis.core import *
import os

def run_script():
    path = QgsProject.instance().readPath(".{0}".format(os.sep))
    path = os.getcwd()
    dir = "Submit"
    mif_path = os.sep.join([path, dir, "MID_MIF"]) + os.sep
    shape_path = os.sep.join([path, dir, "ESRI_SHAPE"]) + os.sep

    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.mkdir(dir)
    if not os.path.exists(mif_path):
        os.mkdir(mif_path)
    if not os.path.exists(shape_path):
        os.mkdir(shape_path)

    for vlayer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        file_path = "{0}{1}.mif".format(mif_path, vlayer.name())
        options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
        options.driverName = "Mapinfo File"
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(
            vlayer, file_path, QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options
        )

    for vlayer in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        file_path = "{0}{1}.shp".format(shape_path, vlayer.name())
        options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
        options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(
            vlayer, file_path, QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), options
        )

    QMessageBox.information(None, "MapInfo Mif/Mid Exported to", "" + mif_path)
    QMessageBox.information(None, "ESRI Shapefile to", "" + shape_path)
```

The main changes are the switch between `PyQt4` into `PyQt5`, and update to `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2`.

Comment: Be careful, fstring is nice but it is still early and is not supported on all Python 3 versions. Some users might come later with this bug.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!!Can you please clarify your last comments RE 'Transform...'. Is this another step required to export to the formats.

Comment: Please excuse my naivety with this... i get the following error.
 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'QMessageBox' from 'PyQt5.QtGui' (C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtGui.pyd)

Comment: @etrimaille: switching f-string to classic format.

Comment: @TeeM: No other steps, I clarify the last comment. I corrected also this error, `QMessageBox` belongs to `PyQt5.QtWidgets`.

Comment: @J.Monticolo: i do not get any errors now, but what would stop this from creating the folders and output files, and displaying the Messagebox at the end?

Comment: @TeeM: I don't get your last question. This code product the same thing as your original code.

Comment: Sorry. 
I mean that it doesn’t actually create the output files shape and mid/mif files.  

My original code worked on earlier versions of QGIS, and created folders and output files.

Comment: @TeeM: here is just a Python function. You have to call it to make it work. At the end of your code, place a not indented line with `run_script()`, that will call your function.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was missing. 

Thanks so much for your assistance.